# Labelling and Referencing Multiple Custom Counters Together

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, counters, labels

This is what I have.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcounter{theorem}[section]
\newcommand\theorem{\stepcounter{theorem}\framebox{\textbf{Theorem \thesection.\thetheorem}}}

\begin{document}
\section{New Section}

\theorem \label{t1}

\theorem \label{t2}

\ref{t1}

\ref{t2}

\end{document}
```

It shows :

```
1  New Section
Theorem 1.1
Theorem 1.2
1
1
```

I would like it to show this instead :

```
1  New Section
Theorem 1.1
Theorem 1.2
1.1
1.2
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

(I'm aware of the `\newtheorem` command but I don't want my text automatically italicized and I want my text to start on a new paragraph, which is why I went with making my own `\theorem` command, but now I'm having difficulty referencing the two custom counters that I have, together. I also accidentally made a duplicate account to which I can't login to to delete the duplicate post I made as I'm not sure how to logout from my actual account.)

Comment: Welcome! Can you please make your snippet compilable?

Comment: You need `\refstepcounter` rather than `\stepcounter`.

Comment: It isn't obvious what is producing the `1` and `1` in your 'output', so it isn't obvious what should be producing the `1.1` and `1.2` you want instead.

Comment: Apologies. I've edited it now. I was using \ref to get the output. What does \refstepcounter do? How is it different to \stepcounter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To tell LaTeX that this is an element you want to cross-reference, you need `\refstepcounter` rather than `\stepcounter`. Otherwise, your labels just get references to the section counter which, as you've seen, is 1 throughout the example.

To ensure the cross-references include the section counter, you can customise the output of `\thetheorem` to include the counter.

For example,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcounter{theorem}[section]
\renewcommand\thetheorem{\thesection.\arabic{theorem}}
\newcommand\theorem{\refstepcounter{theorem}\framebox{\textbf{Theorem \thetheorem}}}

\begin{document}
\section{New Section}

\theorem \label{t1}

\theorem \label{t2}

\ref{t1}

\ref{t2}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image: sections and theorems]

Comment: Thank you! One quick question though, how do you get the last bit to show up on your answer? Is that a screenshot of the compiled PDF?

Comment: @ChungRenKhoo Yes. It is a screenshot (PNG) which I uploaded when posting my answer.

Comment: @ChungRenKhoo If you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) *and* marking it as [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: Yep. I have done that. (I think) It doesn't register my upvote publicly as I'm still below 15 rep (that's what it says anyways).

Comment: You need upvotes/reputation to be able to do something in this forum.  I've upvoted your question.  ;-)

Comment: Ah thank you. Can actually see my vote counting towards the public poll now. :D